# Does imaginary part of complex number represents the meaning of down payment or stealing in real life??

Tags: complex-numbers

I am new to complex numbers and trying to understand them and find real life conditions which could be interpreted by them "like positive one apple is gained apple and negative one apple is lost apple....so what is `+1i` apple and `-1i`apple" ....

I know that electromagnetism ,ac, wave analysis and quantum mechanics are explained by complex numbers but i can not hold them in my hand like apples...
So i had first thought that `+1i` may represent the situation when two persons A,B are making bets "gambling" over the result of match
And from point of view of person A : person A put `-1i` dollar with intermediate person ,person B put `+1i` dollar with the intermediate person .....
Here for person A, I consider the dollar he gives for the intermediary person `-1i` because if he loses, he transfers this `-1i` dollar to real `-1` dollar ....
and the dollar given by B to the intermediary is `+1i` relative to A because if A wins he converts this `+1i` into real `+1` dollar...
I do not know if my understanding is right but i continue to study complex numbers and i solve the following problem :
`p(x)=-0.3x^2 +50 x-170` where `p` is the profit and `x` is the lamps produced per week.
"note here that i do not know the price of lamp or the cost of manufacturing and that the profit is nonlinear"
then I try to find number of lamps which make profit of `3000` dollars.
the solution is complex number with real part `83.3333` and imaginary part  `+-60.1849i`.
Now i try to get profit for real part alone "`1913.3333`"and imaginary part alone"`916.6667`" then add them together but the result is `2830` not `3000`.how this is possible????
Note that `2830 +170 =3000`????!!!

During this thinking i tried to calculate the imaginary part after conversion to real `60.1849` ,then i thought of this positive imaginary part as taking full price in advance "down payment of `1752.5783`" for future production "to get beyond the maximum profit per week of `1913.3333`" and I thought of the negative imaginary part as stealing this `60` lamps from the deal and reselling them so we also get beyond barrier of weekly maximum profit...
but calculations for both cases were not equal to `3000`  "`1913.3333 + 1752.5783 = 3665.9117`"
does my guessings about meanings of imaginary part as price in advance or stealing true???

I know that my question may be vague ... this is because i am confused about meaning of complex numbers and i will accept all edits to make it more clear...

Comment: There's no direct analog of complex numbers as physical entities. You shouldn't be surprised, though. There's also no good analog of negative numbers, or of the number $10^{10^{100}}$, or of a lot of other abstract mathematical concepts. Complex numbers, nevertheless, are useful, since they add lots of structure to concepts like exponentials or polynomials, which can then be used to prove more general results about them.

Comment: i see your point of view and i read about it in many sites....but there was this mathematician who described the area of land getting under water during sea tide as being negative area and thus if its shape is square then the side of this square will be square root of negative number....this is what encourages me to try to find real life examples of imaginary numbers till i gave up or find something which confirms that i really understand what complex numbers are for real

Comment: I think the term "imaginary" can be misleading. I've looked around and perhaps this article can help you understand things better: https://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-intuitive-guide-to-imaginary-numbers/.

Comment: @ahmedallam I mean, if I suddenly decide that $1$ milliliter of water is actually $i$ bazzonkles, then it might be that I'm able to drink imaginary amounts of fluids. But that's not really meaningful, is it? Talking about the side of a square with negative area feels similar to me. Even if negative areas can make sense on their own, that's more of a signing convention – it's pretty much meaningless to talk about one of the sides of such a figure having an imaginary length.

Comment: @URL as complex numbers are numbers ,not just tweaks of number system to solve problems,then they must represent something which really exists....so 1 millilitre represents water drop ,-1 milliltre will represent evaporation of this drop and +1i milliltre might represent "for me" rain drop falling to my hand,and -1i milliltre is drop of water jumping from my hand in air "which might get back to my hand and be +1 or fall to ground and be -1........or i am just imagining all of this :)

Comment: I don't think that if you consider numbers to be quantitative amounts like 5 apples that complex numbers will have any good analogy.  A better analogy might be if real numbers are a angular momentum of physical force that is either forward or backwards but multiplying by a complex number can give it torque.

Comment: If you view a complex number as a positive magnitude (absolute vale) and an angular direction (a positive real number has angle of 0, and a negative real has angle of 180 and every non-zero complex number will have an angle between).  Then multiplying multiples the magnitudes and adds the angle.  I don't think *any* model will work unless a number represents a 2-d quantity with two *different* things being measured.  And the best model will have one of the components is period and circular and the other is magnitudinal.

Comment: @fleablood this is good analogy... here i think that force is on real axis and the angle will be vector from origin to certain complex number and multiplication leads to torque.....ok but the angle here is not quantity as mass  or force "based on mass" but angle is just pure direction which we will use complex plane  properties to ease calculations

Comment: To complement @fleablood: If complex numbers have any “real world” representation, it’s as vectors. Adding or multiplying complex numbers is in close analogy to adding or rotating vectors. That also seems to be what you’re getting at, although in a much more abstract manner. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @URL vectors are really great tool to include two givens in one variable .....solving function in two variables is another great tool to include two givens in one entity ....these two tools were used to discover complex numbers....they approximate the 2d complex plane domain to our mind using the already understood 2d plane of both domain and range....but we can not say that vector is complex number analogy....as vector here is formed of 2 different entities "the length and the angle of rotation " each of them is real value....but complex number is single entity

Comment: "as vector here is formed of 2 different entities"  But a vector is a single *thing*.....  A complex number is formed of two different entities also.  A real component and an imaginary component.

Comment: @fleablood you are right....they might be same thing....in this case i can use vectors to solve the quadratic equation and it will give me vector to values which make 3000dollars as profit....i can then see what these numbers represents on number lines and might find the reason why 83.3333+or-60.1849i lamps give profit of 3000 and 83.3333 lamps alone gives 1913 dollars and 60.1849 lamps give 1752 dollars ...both in real giving 3665 dollars.......and both separately added gives 2830+or-3009 i not 3000.....i will try to resolve this problem thinking of complex numbers as vectors

Comment: @URL  Neither of those examples you gave are abstract.  Negative numbers represent balance.  If someone has $0$ dollars and they owe someone $5$ dollars, then they have $-5$ dollars.  $\left({10^{10}}\right)^{100}$ is a natural number, so what's the deal there?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw Negative numbers can represent balance, but $-5 isn’t something you can grab with your hand. Neither is such a huge amount of money as what I said. They’re just abstractions. Useful, commonplace ones, but abstractions. Same thing goes for complex numbers.

Comment: @URL that makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Actually no number really exists. The natural numbers are just a convention for counting things. Like, an apple is represent by 1, and see an apple together with another apple is represent by 2, and so on. But for example, you can't say what does means having -1 apple, or $\pi$ apples.

Basically math is about making some "arbitrary" definitions that makes things good. You can define whatever you want (if it is not self contradictory, like let $x=1$ and $x\neq 1)$, but you try to define things in such way that you get good results.

For example, think about analytic geometry. Its about describing plane geometric things. The usually $xy-$plane are useful for, for example, describing straight lines, because the equations are simple, like $y=2x$. But describing rotations on the $xy-$plane, usually, leads to really complicated equations, involing $\sin$ and $\cos$. How can we avoid this?

Think you want to describe plane geometric things, but you are more interested in some rotations. Instead of thinking about the $xy$ plane, why don't you introduce a "vector component" $w$ that rotate things?
For example, if you have some vector $v$ and multiply this component, you would have the same vector $v$, but rotated by $90º$ ($\pi/2$ radians) counter-clockwise.
Now see that if you have the number 1 (which, in the $xy-$ plane would be the vector $(1,0)$) and apply this component $w$, since multiplying things by 1 intuitively keeps it fixed, you have $1w=w.$ Multiply $w$ again, and you have $1ww=ww=w^{2}.$ But applying $w$ twice means rotating $180º$ ($\pi$ radians). The vector $(1,0)$  in the $xy-$plane rotated $180º$ is the vector $(-1,0),$ namely $-1$. So, you have $w^{2}=-1$.

So, the component $w$ satisfies $w^{2}=-1.$ Well, the mathematicians use to denote this component $w$ by $i$, so $i^{2}=-1.$

That is a way to understand the complex number, and my favorite one.

Comment: Your first sentence is very dubious. At best it is meaningless, or doesn't really exist, for what it's worth.

Comment: Which sentence?

Comment: The $1$st: *Actually no number really exists...*

Answer (score 2):

This is just an illustration of what Mateus Rocha has already said, but since it relates the usage of complex numbers to a real world problem, I thought it might help you in coming to grips with the use of complex numbers.

I work for an aircraft manufacturer, and we needed to figure out the location of the landing gear axles on an aircraft as it sits on the ground. For most of our aircraft models, the main landing gear use a [trailing link configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing-arm_suspension#/media/File:Oleo_trailing_link_main_landing_gear.JPG). This consists of a trunnion extending from the aircraft, with a bar (the "trailing link") connected to the trunnion by a pivot extending back to hold the wheel. A shock absorber (the "oleo") also connects to the trunnion to the trailing link. The location of the axle depends on how compressed the oleo is. Here is a simplified view of the geometry:
[image]

The location of the pivot and the anchor are known constants, as well as the distances from pivot to oleo attachment and axle. By taking a measurement of the oleo, we can know all sides of the triangle and can calculate the location of the attachment point, and therefore also the axle.

When I first did this calculation, I solved it using vectors, setting the origin at the Pivot. The Anchor was a known vector, and I rotated it down to the axle line by the amount needed to make the Oleo the right length.

The algebraic calculation was rather messy. But I reproduced the calculation in a number of variants of the tools we used, until at some point I noticed that a formula I was looking at was exactly like complex multiplication. Suddenly it occurred to me that I had been doing it the hard way.

If I view this as the complex plane, with $0$ at the pivot, and represent the Anchor, Attachment, and Axle as complex numbers, the rotation of Anchor to Attachment is just one complex multiplication, and converting the Attachment to the Axle is another (which in the actual calculation is not a real number, as the Pivot, Attachment, and Axle are not really in a straight line). The Oleo length is $|\text{Anchor} - \text{Attachment}|$, which made the calculation of their ratio more sensible as well.

---

The point is, any real-world calculation involving a complex number can be thought of instead as a calculation involving 2 real numbers. So it is never necessary to bring in complex numbers. But there are times when *conceptually* it is easier to work with complex numbers than pairs of real numbers (in the case of quantum mechanics, so much easier that it boggles the mind how hard it would be to express otherwise).

Comment: `The point is, any real-world calculation involving a complex number can be thought of instead as a calculation involving 2 real numbers.` this is very helpful....that is what i am trying to do exactly....i am trying to convert the imag part of lamps to real and calculate their profit and then add them to the profit of real part ...but yesterday i was missing the 3rd term 2ab"a^2+b^2+2ab"... now i am recalculating and if real profit +imag profit +3rd term got me 3000 then my understanding will be true and imag part is just a definition of condition of "to be +real or to be -real for +i and -i"

Comment: I'm glad to help, but note that more often it is conceptually *harder* to do something in complex numbers than as a pair of real numbers. In my case, complex numbers were useful because they handily capture rotations and magnifications, as Mateus Rocha has said, and that is exactly what I needed. In your situation, I personally don't see where the properties of complex numbers would be helpful, so to me it seems like you are only adding complication.

Answer (score 2):

My take may be a little bit of a simplistic view, but every time that I have dealt with complex numbers, I have always been able to interpret them as some sort of "rotation". In some sense, this is what complex numbers describe.

To use your analogy of gambling, the way that I would interpret that situation would be something like 1+1i to mean the player is gaining a dollar per round but is also cycling a dollar. You would expect that the gambler will experience his wealth increasing by about a dollar per round, but will sometimes be ahead of that trendline by about a dollar, and sometimes will be below that trendline by about a dollar. You would expect an ordinary sinusoidal pattern, if you detrended the line.

If you understand the equation:
$$e^{i\pi}+1=0$$
you will start to understand why complex numbers sort of imply rotations. This formula has deep ties to trigonometric functions, and thus circles.

Paul Sinclar's answer describes how he solved for the rotation of a shock absorbing system, and how he figured out that it was easier to work with complex numbers. The vector math was messy, and it was solved by rotating the system. But then he realized it was cleaned up the math to think about the system in the complex plane (because that is where rotations happen).

Quantum mechanics you are dealing with angular momentum which is just a fancy way of saying that things spin/rotate and that has to be conserved. So it is no wonder that complex numbers help to clean up some gnarly partial differential equations in that domain.

For your lamp example, the closest that you can get is by producing 83 lamps. Now, this answer isn't very helpful since the answer is not going to give you back $3000. In some sense, though, the complex number tells you that you need to "spiral" out from 83 lamps (positive imaginary number) with something like an angular component of 60 lamps. Strange interpretation, but it is a static univariate problem and I'm doing my best.

The imaginary number in this case, is more likely telling you that it is not feasible to get your target profit with current production technologies. One interpretation that I like is a little sci-fi, it is how many lamps you would need to produce and rotate into our universe from a parallel universe to achieve your target. Silly interpretation, I suppose, but it gives you an idea that the target you are hoping to hit is not feasible.